# String to jsonobject in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, string

This is string from jsonObject

```
[
    {
        "No": "1",
        "Name": "ABC"
    },
    {
        "No": "2",
        "Name": "PQR"
    },
    {
        "No": "3",
        "Name": "XYZ"
    }
]
```

I want convert to this string to JSONObject to get this value in JSONArray

Comment: Which of the many libraries are you using?

Comment: Google can give you better results. And surprisingly, in this case, [Google's gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is there for your rescue.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this one:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
// ...

String jsonStr = "[{\"No\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"ABC\"},{\"No\":\"2\",\"Name\":\"PQR\"},{\"No\":\"3\",\"Name\":\"XYZ\"}]";

   JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonStr); 

    for(int i=0; i<array.length(); i++){
        JSONObject jsonObj  = array.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("No"));
        System.out.println(jsonObj.getString("Name"));
    }
```

Output:

```
1
ABC
2
PQR
3
XYZ
```

Comment: from which package JSONArray is imported?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu for example: `org.json.JSONArray`

Comment: it will be better to add these two answer as it gives more clarity to the answer.thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Use Google's JSON library (google-gson):

```
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(your json string);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse JSON strings into Java objects and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose your input string is str,

```
 String str = {"xyz":[{"name":"apple","email_id":"apple@apple.com"}]}

 JSONObject json = JSONObject.fromObject(str);

 JSONArray jarr = json.getJSONArray("xyz");
```

Inplace of xyz, you can pass root string input.

This should work.

Comment: Add what package is this `JSONObject` because is not from `org.json.simple.JSONObject`