# Parse string and remove space and new line and convert to json OBJECT

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a string in the following manner how can i convert this string to JSON object.. My string is

```
{\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]}
```

Please help to convert the above string to JSON Object.

I tried with the following code but still i am getting string value not an object

```
  var body = " {\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]} ".replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, "");
    var json=body.replace(/['"]+/g, '');
    var object = JSON.stringify(json);
    object = JSON.parse(object)
```

Comment: Why not fixing the source of error. how are you getting this string?

Comment: Take a look in this article: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400867/string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

Comment: just use `body = " ... ".replace(/,\s*?}/g, '}')`. But better fix origin of the problem.

Comment: It looks like `JSON.parse("...")` should just work. No need for all the other stuff you are doing. Are the `\"` really part of the raw data, or where does they come from? It almost looks like you are double encoding the original data.

Comment: Why do you do replace and stringify? Shouldn't JSON.parse simple create an object from JSON String?.

Comment: @FelixKling JSON is malformed, so it won't.

Comment: @dfsq: Looks fine to me if put in a string literal (what the OP seems to be doing).

Comment: @dfsq: Ah, I see now.

Comment: @FelixKling Assuming that what is he is saying that the string contains a physical backslash followed by a physical double quote mark, or a physical backslash followed by a physical letter "n", which I somehow suspect may be the case, then no, of course, `JSON.parse` will not work.

Comment: @torazaburo: If it is put in the a string literal, like the OP does, then it will. `"{\"foo\": 42}"` will create a string containing valid JSON. I think the question is missing a lot of context information.

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) you are certain that the string contains no evil parts (that is, you are sure of the origin of the data and it's integrity), it would probably be easiest to use `eval`:

```
var body = " {\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]} ";
eval("var object = " + body);
console.log(object);
```

Comment: Why not use `JSON.parse`?

Comment: If the asker can influence what the string looks like, obviously there is no issue at all. I assume the weirdly formed string comes from somewhere, e.g. some other system asker has no influence over.

Answer (score 0):

As dfsq suggested, remove the commas (,) before the end brace (}) before parsing it out:

```
var body = " {\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]} ".replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "").replace(/\s+/g, "").replace(/,}/g,'}');
var object = JSON.parse(body);
```

Or without removing extra spaces and newlines:

```
var body = " {\"Warranty\": [ \n { \n \"Name\": \"test\", \n \"Type\": \"test2\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"Test6\", \n \"Type\": \"test7\", \n \"Months\": \"6\", \n }, \n { \n \"Name\": \"test9\", \n \"Type\": \"test10\", \n \"Miles\": \"10000\", \n } \n ]} ".replace(/,\s*}/g,'}');
var object = JSON.parse(body);
```

Comment: Don't remove line breaks and spaces.

Comment: That was from his original code.  I agree it is unnecessary.  Perhaps he is trying to minify the JSON.

Comment: then use regexp dfsq suggested, it at least doesn't remove *all* white spaces

Comment: Added another version that only replaces trailing commas before close brace.