# Get JSON from URL and create JSON Object

Tags: android, json, urlconnection

I'm using Async task + HttpURLConnection to get [this JSON](http://bitcoinstats.azurewebsites.net/api/ExchangeVolume) in Android. And I'm trying to parse it with JSONObject. Here is my Class:

```
public class getData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://bitcoinstats.azurewebsites.net/api/ExchangeVolume");
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
            }catch( Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            return result.toString();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            //Do something with the JSON string
            //result = result.replace("\\", "");
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                tv.setText("Converted");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Error converting to json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                tv.setText(result);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //tv.setText(result);
        }

    }
```

Observation: tv is a texview of my page, which I print the result on.

My problem is that the JSONException is been throwed, and I don't know why. The JSON is valid, I checked in http://jsonlint.com/ , and I'm receiving the json correctly, because I can print it in the TextViewer perfectly. So why is this simple creation of a JSONObject from a String is not working?

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of the `e.printStackTrace();`, please?

Comment: your json contains unwanted tag < string xmlns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" >& </String> try to remove from server side.

Comment: After hiting this request gettting xml response not pure json which conatins above  mentioned tag http://bitcoinstats.azurewebsites.net/api/ExchangeVolume

Comment: Can you try UTF-8 - `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"))`?

Comment: @itechevo just tryed, same error..

Comment: @Suhas , this tags only show in browser, when I print in the app they are not there. Even, I tried to remove them programatically, it didn't work, and I have no idea how to remove it from server.

Comment: @Ernani just try my answer.

Comment: @Ernani Hit your request in chrome Rest client and check the json error

Comment: @Ernani Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Result you are getting is in the form of XML. 
So you have to first parse the xml and then json object.

```
String response = response_from_URL
response = response.replaceAll("<string>", "");
response = response.replaceAll("</string>", "");
```

Comment: I don't know why, when you open with the browser there is that fancy microsoft XML, but I printed in the App and there was no XML, just the JSON.

Comment: Pardon? What you mean? Answer is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe "result" isn't formatted correctly?

Check this example: [String to jsonobject in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19400867/string-to-jsonobject-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you too.

[How to automate login a website](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Your response comes within `<String> </String>`. Therefore, you have to remove `<String> </String>`, and then do as regularly.

```
result = result.replaceAll("<string>", "");
result = result.replaceAll("</string>", "");
```

now

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
```

Hope this works for you

Answer (score 0):

The response contains a `<string>` tag around the `JSON`. We can remove it by regex matching using the `Pattern` class. Then convert it to `JSONObject`.

Try this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {
        Pattern sPattern = Pattern.compile("<string xmlns=\".*\">(.*)<\\/string>");
        Matcher m = sPattern.matcher(result);
        if (m.find()) {
            result = m.group(1);
        }
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
        result = json.getString("timestamp");
        tv.setText(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Error converting to json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        tv.setText(result);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

//it  first replace \ & after that extra " from result.

            result= result.replace("\\",""); 
            result = result.replaceFirst("\"","");

            Log.d("Test","Result:"+result);
            //Do something with the JSON string
            //result = result.replace("\\", "");
            try {
                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                Log.d("Test",json.toString());
    //            tv.setText("Converted");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
    //            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    //                    "Error converting to json", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
    //                    .show();
    //            tv.setText(result);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //tv.setText(result);
        }
```

[image: After Run code and take result in Asyntask PostExcute() method]

[image: Rest client shows]

Comment: this will give you correct Json as you need. To get that we need to apply string replace functions.

Answer (score 0):

I was using Microsoft Azure to host the API that sent me the JSON that I wanted. The code was made in C#, and strangely, return the "toString()" of a JSON object and try to use it in my Android App wasn't possible, some weird things were coming with the code. Anyway, a friend of my, show me how to proper return values.

Basically I replaced the type of return with "HttpResponseMessage", the java code above works fine.