# Issue converting JSON string to JSON array or JSON object in android app after removing Slash "\" characters

Tags: java, android, json

Good day ,pls i have this problem that has been kicking me head.I have a JSON String as follows:

```
"{\"operations\":[{\"AccountType\":\"15516321\",\"CustomerName\":\"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"1100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"}]}]}"
```

**However when i apply this piece of code:**

```
String jsonFormattedString = new JSONTokener(responseBody.string()).nextValue().toString();
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);
JSONArray myJsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("operations");
```

**or this one:**

```
String DataString  = responseBody.string().replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
                        JSONObject myJsonObject = new JSONObject(DataString);
```

to remove the slashes it truncates a part of my JSON string as follows:

**TRUNCATED CODE HERE->**  {"{\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"ValueDate\":\"16\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":105,\"ValueDate\":\"17\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":107,\"ValueDate\":\"18\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":109,\"ValueDate\":\"19\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":111,\"ValueDate\":\"20\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":113,\"ValueDate\":\"21\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":115,\"ValueDate\":\"22\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":117,\"ValueDate\":\"23\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":119,\"ValueDate\":\"24\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":121,\"ValueDate\":\"25\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":103,\"ValueDate\":\"16\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":105,\"ValueDate\":\"17\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":107,\"ValueDate\":\"18\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":109,\"ValueDate\":\"19\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":111,\"ValueDate\":\"20\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":113,\"ValueDate\":\"21\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":115,\"ValueDate\":\"22\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":117,\"ValueDate\":\"23\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":119,\"ValueDate\":\"24\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\"},{\"ID\":121,\"ValueDate\":\"25\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25\/12\/2016 02:53:52\",\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putti   **<- TRUNCATED CODE HERE**

Please what can i do to remove the slashes without loosing a part of the data
here is my android code for the GET Request to WebApi:

```
 public final class OkHttpHandlerIncoming {

        String URL = "http://192.168.1.101/UnicsApplication/api/uconnectservice";

        JSONObject jsonObject;
        private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        public void run() throws Exception {
            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(URL).build();

            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                    try (ResponseBody responseBody = response.body()) {

                        if (!response.isSuccessful())

                            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();

                        for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {

                            Log.d("Results", responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));

                        }
                        //Log.d("Results", responseBody.string());

                        try {
                            //get JSON object first 
                            String jsonFormattedString = new JSONTokener(responseBody.string()).nextValue().toString();

                            JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(jsonFormattedString);



                            JSONArray myJsonArray = jo.getJSONArray("operations");

                            // creates a new JSON Object with the given keys
                            JSONObject result = myJsonArray.toJSONObject(myJsonArray);






                            Log.d("JsonObject", result.toString());

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Please any help will be greatly appreciated,cheers

Comment: You don't have a JSON string at all. That's just a String, which happens to contain a JSON object. You don't need to replace the backslashes, you need to a) fix the API b) Read the response correctly

Comment: I assume `new JSONObject(responseBody.string())` is what you need.

Comment: It seems, Your Json String is incorrect . http://stackoverflow.com/a/19401006/892788

Comment: @cricket_007,have tried that to no avail :(

Comment: Is your API Javascript based? Then you need to not `JSON.stringify`, for example.

Comment: If not, when you did try that, what was the error?

Comment: Just now i have tried using : JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
     JsonElement element = jsonParser.parse(responseBody.string()); but it still truncates a part of my result. JSON Data is coming from WebApi service to m android app

Comment: @cricket_007 i recieve this error :org.json.JSONException: Value { of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to

Comment: this is how the code i use on server side WebApi: var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                operations = sampledata.GetAllDummy()
            });

Comment: Okay, newtonsoft... That method is serializing what appears to be a JSON string already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the slash as:-

```
    String data=  "{\"operations\":[{\"AccountType\":\"15516321\",\"CustomerName\":\"1MACMONSAM NICOLAS\",\"Currentbalance\":\"1100,000.00\",\"AllTransactions\":[{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"15009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I'am putting in money right now\",\"Debit\":\"150010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":103,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5001\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"16/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":105,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5002\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"17/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":107,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5003\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"18/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":109,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5004\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"19/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":111,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5005\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"20/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":113,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5006\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"21/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":115,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5007\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"22/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":117,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5008\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"23/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":119,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"5009\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"24/12/2016 01:55:32\"},{\"ID\":121,\"DescriptionoOfTransaction\":\"I need money right now\",\"Debit\":\"50010\",\"Credit\":\"0\",\"TransactionDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\",\"ValueDate\":\"25/12/2016 01:55:32\"}]}]}";

String value=data.replaceAll("\"","");
```

But your Json is not in correct format. It has some error.

Comment: ut i'm using:var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
            {
                operations = sampledata.GetAllDummy(),
                Formatting.Indented
            });  to get JSON from service

Answer (score 0):

First of all, This is server side problem. Server should be responsible for such mistakes -

still,

To replace backslash from string:-
Use

```
strTarget = strTarget.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

or

```
strTarget= strTarget.replace("\\", "");
```

You have to double escape backslash while using `replaceAll()` because it considers the first argument as a regex. while in `replace()`, string considered as literal string, so that you have backspace only once.

Comment: This is a poor solution to the actual problem - the API is returning an escaped JSON string. The client shouldn't be responsible for fixing the server's mistakes

Comment: Yes I would prefer that too.

Comment: thnx @wizard/@cricket_007